# Python 2.7 Tkinter: how do I click & release on two widgets and get responses from both?

Tags: python, python-2.7, events, tkinter, bind

I hope you can help me with a problem I have in python 2.7. I couldn't find a solution online, but I'm honestly unsure what keywords to search for, so I'm sorry if this is redundant.

The code below is an example of my problem.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

#Widgets.
btn1 = tk.Label(root, text="btn1", bg="gray80")
btn2 = tk.Label(root, text="btn2", bg="gray80")
btn1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
btn2.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

#Widget events.
def onClick1(event):
    print "Clicked button 1."
def onRelease1(event):
    print "Released button 1."
def onClick2(event):
    print "Clicked button 2."
def onRelease2(event):
    print "Released button 2."

#Bindings.
btn1.bind("<Button-1>", onClick1, add="+")
btn1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", onRelease1, add="+")
btn2.bind("<Button-1>", onClick2, add="+")
btn2.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", onRelease2, add="+")

root.mainloop()
```

Whenever I click one button (technically a label) and hold it, the onClick event for it fires, but if I drag the mouse over to the other and release it, I get the same onRelease as the one I clicked, and not the one for the label I have my mouse over currently. This has held me back some time now, and I'd hate to scrap the whole feature in my program I need this for, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release event always fires on the same widget that got the press event. Within your handler you can ask tkinter what widget is under the cursor.

Example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

btn1 = tk.Label(root, text="btn1", bg="gray80")
btn2 = tk.Label(root, text="btn2", bg="gray80")
btn1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
btn2.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

def onRelease(event):
    x,y = event.widget.winfo_pointerxy()
    widget = event.widget.winfo_containing(x, y)
    print("widget:", widget.cget("text"))

btn1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", onRelease)
btn2.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", onRelease)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It works! Needs some twists to fit my real code, but this method looks promising. Thank you.